# PHP: Copy() producing empty files

Tags: php

I am using the following function to `copy()` a file, The files are typically 1-50KB in size and a file of the correct name is created but it is completely empty.

```
public function backup() {
    $backup = $this->_root.'/cfg_'.date('d_m_y').'.backup';
    if (!copy($this->_file, $backup))
        return false;
    return $backup;
}
```

I know for certain that `$this->_file` correctly points to the file I am attempting to copy. `$this->_file` is created by another method of the same class and I perform a `chmod()` with an octal value of 0755 on it as shown in the following function:

```
private function createFile($filename) {
    if (!($this->_pointer = @fopen($filename, 'cb')))
        return false;
    fclose($this->_pointer);
    chmod($filename, 0755);
    return true;
}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: set error_reporting  =  E_ALL in your php.ini and debug it again

Comment: What does the copy return? If you print out the values of `$this->_file`, `$this->_root` etc., does the php *file* `<?php var_export($copy('/this->_root_value/cfg_...', '...'));` produce the same result?

Comment: @palmic error_reporting is already set to E_ALL

Comment: @phihag I think you are on to something. By printing out the values of `$this->_file`, `$this->_root` and running your code it returns `true` and the file has the correct data inside.

Comment: @George That means that we *cannot possible help you*, since the error is in the setup of the function, and not the function itself. Are you certain that the input file exists *at the time* that `backup` is called (and is not created,renamed, etc. by code afterwards)?

Comment: @phihag Indeed I am, the file is created in the constructor, and if I refresh the script it will be using the file created by the last one which means there is no way it couldn't exist atleast from the second time the script is accessed. The input file is never renamed and has a static hardcoded name saved to a variable. I save it's name to `$this->_file` at the beginning of the constructor and use that in my `createFile()` function. To call the backup function I merely do this `if (!$backup = $this->backup())`

Comment: @phihag I think i just realised what the problem is. I am calling `backup()` after I call `fopen()` on it which is truncating it so the file is actually empty at the time of backup :)

Comment: @George Looks like "problem solved" to me :D. Please go ahead and write that into an answer (and maybe a hint of how to find it, like `When I examined the code that creates the file, I noticed that it truncates the file; the file content is only written afterwards`) and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem solved:** The issue was that I performed an `fopen()` call on the `$this->_file` like so:

```
if (!($this->_pointer = @fopen($this->_file, "wb")))
    throw new Exception("Unable to retrieve database configuration");
```

This caused `$this->_file` to be truncated and I had not yet written to it so at the time my `copy()` operation was performed `$this->_file` was empty itself and thus showed no error.

Apologies to the folks who gave answers as the function that was doing the `fopen()` call was not included in my question.

Comment: More specifically, it's the `w` flag which was truncating the file. You probably want `ab` to open for binary-mode writing at the end of the file.

Comment: @adam I am purposefully truncating the file, which is why I was making the backup in the first place :P

Answer (score 1):

One obvious thing is to make sure you have got free space at the location you are copying to.

Comment: Indeed I do, I have a large amount of hosting space and have used very little.

Comment: @George Try reducing your script to absolutely simplest form, in small steps. Ideally, try producing one-line script with `copy()` with hard-coded parameters. Probably somewhere on the way from your current script to that debugging form you will find the bug. Or you will find the bug in your system. :)

Comment: Thanks ash but my script is too complex to do this. The files don't exist without the script and it's not small and spans 4 classes.

Comment: @George Still, the general debug strategy useful here is divide and conquer: isolate the problematic code. Add all possible pre-checks and post-checks: make sure that the source file exists right before `copy()` and check the backup file size right after `copy()`. E.g. `system("ls -l " . escapeshellarg($this->_file));` if you are on a unix-like system.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permissions issue. Are you sure the script has read permission on the file? Provided that $this->_file is a valid path, I can't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: It should do, the file it is copying is also generated from the script and I `chmod()` it to an octal value of 0755 upon creation.